# Django one to many relationship: number of objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, one-to-many, django-queryset

here is my models:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=False, null=True)
    .
    .
    .

class Comment(models.Model):
    on_story = models.ForeignKey(Story, related_name="comments", blank=False, null=False)
    .
    .
    .
```

How do I get the number of **comments** related to a specific **Story**, and inject that into a view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`QuerySet.count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#count) through `comments` attribute (related_name).

Use the following in the view function:

```
comment_count = specific_story.comments.count()
# do something with `comment_count`
```

**UPDATE** Use `.comments.count` in template:

```
{% for story in stories %}
    ... {{ story.comments.count }} ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If I implement my view like this:

    def index(request):
 story_list = Story.objects.order_by("-date_published")
    .
    .
    .
    context = {'stories': stories}
    return render(request, 'stories/index.html', context)

How do I get the number of comments for individual stories in my template?

Comment: @Lumsum, I updated the answer after reading your comment. Please check it out.

Comment: You could have just called comments.count in the template, actually.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, You're right. I forgot that method call is possible in template. Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I just asked similar question [link]:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423523/django-get-count-of-photos-by-gallery-beside-gallery-name#31423628) and got similar answers.  I found the annotate answer below to be faster by about 3x, not surprising as query in view is closer to db than operation in template.

Answer (score 4):

If you need the comment count for multiple stories, I would strongly recommend to use [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) instead of calling `comments.count()` on each story:

```
from django.db.models import Count

stories = Story.objects.order_by("-date_published").annotate(comment_count=Count('comments'))
```

This will reduce the number of queries from N+1 to just 1, doing the `COUNT` in the database using joins, instead of a separate query for each count. The count is then accessible as follows:

```
{% for story in stories %}
    {{ story.comment_count }}
{% endfor %}
```