# Django get count of photos by gallery beside gallery name

Tags: python, django

Building Django 1.8 app which is like a photo gallery (my galleries are called 'fountains').  I have a page with list of fountains and I want to show the count of photos beside the fountain name eg:

```
Fountain 1 (49 photos)
Fountain 2 (43 photos)
etc
```

I understand that Django has annotate to aggregate and count records that I have used to create the following:

```
 photo_count = Fountains.objects.all().annotate(Count('photos'))
```

However, what I cannot determine is where to put this.  The documentation just shows the query but doesn't place the query and resulting counts in the context of an application.

I have done this 'photo_count' aggregation in the view that creates the data for the list of fountains.

But my question is, how to get this into the template so it can be shown beside the fountain name?

I guess i have to load it into the template and then associate it with the fountain pk?

Any pointers on what the Django methodology is to get this aggregation from view into the template would be greatly appreciated!

My models:

```
class Fountains(models.Model):
    foun_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    foun_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    foun_address = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True, null=True)
    foun_lat = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    foun_lon = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    #tags = TaggableManager()
    #def __unicode__(self):
    #    return self.foun_name.name

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'fountains'
        #verbose_name_plural = 'Fountains'

class Photos(models.Model):
    #filename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    filename = models.ImageField(upload_to='.')
    ext = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    #fountain_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    fountain = models.ForeignKey(Fountains)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    photos_tag_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    #def __unicode__(self):
    #    return self.filename.name

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'photos'
        #verbose_name_plural = 'Photos'
```

My view that creates the list of fountains:

```
@login_required
def fountains(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    fountain_list = Fountains.objects.order_by('foun_name')
    photo_count = Fountains.objects.all().annotate(Count('photos'))
    context_dict = {'fountains': fountain_list }
    return render(
        request,
        'app/fountains.html',
        context_dict,
        context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    )
```

My template that displays the view results:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Fountains</h1>
    <p><a href="/fountain_add/">Add Fountain</a></p>
    <ul>
    {% for fountain in fountains %}
        <li><a href="/photos/{{ fountain.id }}/"}>{{ fountain.foun_name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor%}
    </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fountain_list = Fountains.objects.annotate(Count('photos')).order_by('foun_name')


<li><a href="/photos/{{ fountain.id }}/"}>{{ fountain.foun_name }} ({{ fountain.photos__count  }})</a></li>
```

Comment: Hey this is great. Nice and compact.  But I had to add the _photo_count_ alias as follows:   _fountain_list = Fountains.objects.annotate(photo_count = Count('photos')).order_by('foun_name')_   I think you intended to put alias in as you used _photo_count_ in template? Or is there something else I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: yes, you are right, i edited answer. Will be photos__count or need add aliace annotate(photo_count=Count('photos'))

Comment: Yes I see, the _{{ fountain.photos__count }}_ without having the alias works too.  What is the significance of the double underscore?  I like the alias just bc it is clearer to read, but the double underscore is more compact.

Answer (score 1):

in your html

```
<h1>Fountains</h1>
    <p><a href="/fountain_add/">Add Fountain</a></p>
    <ul>
    {% for fountain in fountains %}
        <li><a href="/photos/{{ fountain.id }}/"}>{{ fountain.foun_name }} ( {{ fountain.photos.all.count }} )</a></li>
    {% endfor%}
    </ul>
```

Comment: The _{{ fountain.photos.count }}_  didn't work.  I can see how it might if these are related models.  Should it work?

Comment: try this: ( {{ fountain.photos.all.count }} )

Comment: Ok you were close. i did some digging and found that Django does something like what you suggest.  So this works: _{{ fountain.photos_set.count }}_     This method appears to be most efficient, I don't have to do anything extra in the view eg I can just use the original query  _fountain_list = Fountains.objects.order_by('foun_name')_  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the `context_dict` that you create is where you should put your `photo_count`.

```
context_dict = {'fountains': fountain_list, 'photo_count': photo_count}
```

Then you can use this in your templates as normal.
Also, without any knowledge about how your system works, I would rename all of the `foun_` prefixes from the properties in your `Fountain` model.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.  I added _photo_count_ to the context_dict and tried to use it in template eg as _{{ photo_count }}_ but i got blocks of Objects in place of numbers.